# How can I remove a Bootstrap CSS styling for a specific element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a website about Vanilla World of Warcraft using Bootstrap. To get the items tooltips to work, I'm using this resource from **db.vanillagaming.org**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://db.vanillagaming.org/templates/wowhead/js/power.js"></script>
```

I tested it, and it didn't work. After some searching I've noticed that if I removed bootstrap.min.css it works. Some CSS styling of Bootstrap is removing the ability to show the items tooltips.

So, my question is how can I remove the Bootstrap CSS styling of a specific element? In this case an **a** element.

```
<a href="http://db.vanillagaming.org/?spell=20150">Shield Specialization</a>
```

Here is a example: http://codepen.io/diogocapela/pen/QGxLYj

Comment: can you provide live example of your issue?

Comment: Using the power.js provided by db.vanillagaming.org I should be able to use a link to any item on db.vanillagaming.org and when a user on my website mouses over that link, it shows a tooltip with the information about that item.
Without bootstrap CSS that works, but if I include it it doesn't work. So I think CSS overwrites some styling used by that power.js...

Comment: Bootstrap has it's own [tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRzKjX maybe it isn't correct, but i can't see problem

Comment: Bootstrap is not correctly applied. If you try with this doesn't work:
`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> `

Comment: So, any idea how can I solve my problem? =/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is my example: http://codepen.io/diogocapela/pen/QGxLYj

Comment: demo, in your example bootstrap is not correctly applied... Look at the text formating, you can clearly see that it's not bootstrap standard font....

Comment: Look at my example: http://codepen.io/diogocapela/pen/QGxLYj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bootstrap and  db.vanillagaming.org both have some styles for class `.tooltip` they override each other. 
To make it work, You can add one fix : make `.tooltip` visible 
`.tooltip { opacity : 1; }` should fix your problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbZjjZ

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH